# Qiskit: how can you use a different state for each shot in a quantum circuit?

Tags: programming, quantum-gate, qiskit, quantum-state, quantum-circuit

I am trying to run a quantum circuit many times, each time using a different random state - a single qubit i.e. $|\psi\rangle= a|0\rangle + b|1\rangle$ with different $a$ and $b$. Once each qubit has gone through the circuit, I am saving the state vector of the final state, and converting this to spherical coordinates by calculating $\theta$ and $\phi$. I append each $\theta$ and $\phi$ value to a list and then plot them on a histogram (omitted below).

Whilst this works, for large `num_states` it is very slow, so I am wondering if there is a way to use the 'shots' feature when executing the circuit, since you can write:

```
job = execute(qc, backend, shots=1000)
```

I tried playing around with this but found after the initial random state was generated, it repeated the circuit with the same state for the number of shots, rather than doing a different state each time. I'd like to use the shots feature as I believe this will be much quicker since OpenMP is built into Qiskit.

Any ideas on how I might be able to implement a different state each time using shots would be much appreciated:)

````
import numpy as np
from qiskit import(
    QuantumCircuit,
    execute,
    Aer)

from math import pi

from qiskit.quantum_info import random_statevector


#----------------------------------------------------------------------#
backend = Aer.get_backend('statevector_simulator')


def simulate_states(num_states):
    qc = QuantumCircuit(1)

    theta_vals = []
    phi_vals = []
    
    for i in range(num_states):
        
        random_state = random_statevector(2).data
        
        qc.initialize(random_state, 0)
        qc.z(0)
        job = execute(qc, backend)
        result = job.result()
        out_state = result.get_statevector()
    
        theta, phi, alpha_r, alpha_i, beta_r, beta_i = state_coords(out_state)
        theta += pi/2
        
        theta_vals.append(theta)
        phi_vals.append(phi)
        
    return theta_vals, phi_vals

def state_coords(statevector):
    """
    determines the spherical coordinates of a state on the Bloch sphere i.e. calculates \theta and \phi.
    """
    alpha = statevector[0]
    alpha_r = alpha.real
    alpha_i = alpha.imag

    beta = statevector[1]
    beta_r = beta.real
    beta_i = beta.imag

    theta = np.arcsin(2*((alpha_r*beta_r) - (alpha_i*beta_i)))
    phi = 2*np.arccos(2*((alpha_r**2)+(beta_r**2))-1)   
    
    return theta, phi, alpha_r, alpha_i, beta_r, beta_i
```
````

Comment: @luciano this is not a duplicate: tge other question asks about varying the circuit while this one asks about varying the state.

Answer (score 0):

The initial state in a quantum computer is fixed. It is usually taken to the the state $|0\rangle^{\otimes n} $. To vary a single qubit state during the experiment, you must therefore vary the circuit during the experiment, and you **can't** vary the circuit between each shot. However, if you wish to do what you proposed, you can create a list of circuits and each of them has vary quantum state $|\psi\rangle$, then append them together to a list and submit it as a single job.

For example:

```
from qiskit.quantum_info import random_state
from qiskit.aqua.components.initial_states import Custom
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, execute, Aer, IBMQ
from qiskit.tools.monitor import job_monitor
provider = IBMQ.load_account()

num_qubits = 1
random_initial_state = random_state(2**num_qubits)  #create a random state psi
circuits = []
for i in range(100):
    circuit = QuantumCircuit(num_qubits,num_qubits)
    circuit.initialize(random_initial_state, 0)     
    for j in range(num_qubits):
        circuit.measure([j],[j])
    circuits.append(circuit) 

qjob = execute(circuits,shots= 1,backend= Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator'))
job_monitor(qjob)
result = qjob.result()
```

I believe that on the hardware, you can submit up to 900 circuits per job. So you can have up to 900 different states.